# Response Buffer Limit Exceeded classic ASP error

Tags: asp-classic

I did some research about Response Buffer Limit Exceed error and got to know I should use either **Response.Flush()**  or  **<%Response.Buffer = false%>** in my asp code.

I used both of this solution in my code. That is in top of page like this :

```
   <%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %> 
   <%Response.Buffer = false%>
```

And in loop, I am using Response.Flush() before MoveNext that is for example :

```
  Response.Flush()      
  rsCustomer.MoveNext
```

But now problem I am facing is, it is taking too much time to load page. So is there any other solution for this ?

Only solution I dint get to know is increase buffer limit size. In my config file I don't have any code relates to bufferesize.

**Update : Code example :**

```
  table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
   <tr>
    <td style="padding: 2px;" class="bgmed">
        <strong>Customer</strong>
    </td>
    </tr>

     sSQL = "SELECT "
     sSQL = sSQL & " tbl.[Customer]"
     sSQL = sSQL & " FROM tblCart"sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE"
     sSQL = sSQL & "  tbl.[Name] = 'Test'

      </table>
```

This is code example I am using. After calling query, I am binding result to table.

Comment: You're going to have to show us what you're doing in the loop. It will be the other processing throughout that is causing the issue.

Comment: @Paul My code is very lengthy. So posted sample code. Please have a look into that.

Comment: Don't `Response.Flush` on each iteration of the loop use `Mod()` to break it down so it only flushes every so many records. I'm sure I wrote this on a similar post only a few days ago, was that you? Can't find that post anywhere now, did you delete it and repost?

Comment: @Lankymart Hi can you show me how to use Mod() for my code?? And I am not the one who posted that question. Sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use both of those http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525560(v=vs.90).aspx. response.buffer must be true to use response.flush. I don't even know why that is working considering how MSDN states it will cause a run time error.

Also you should not use response.flush in a loop. It would mean you are sending info to the browser every time the loop ends. this would result in way too many pushes to the browser.

**Edit:** Lankymart had mentioned in a comment to use a mod variant of the loop to flush the record more often. adding it to my answer for sake of OP. this is what you would be doing:

```
<%
  sSQL = "SELECT "
  sSQL = sSQL & " tbl.[Customer]"
  sSQL = sSQL & " FROM tblCart"sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE"
  sSQL = sSQL & "  tbl.[Name] = 'Test'
  counter = 0
  rs.Open sSql, ConnectionString
%>
table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 2px;" class="bgmed">
      <strong>Customer</strong>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <%
  Do While Not rs.EoF
    counter = counter + 1
  %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= rs.Fields("Customer").value %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <%
    if counter mod 10 = 0 then
      Response.Flush
    End If
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
  %>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi you are right. Now I am using response.buffer = true. But as you told, when exactly I should use response.flush. Now my pages are loading very slow.

Comment: usually it is used after important menus and site navigation are written. The idea being to allow a user to see that a page exists. In you case I would likely perform it just before your loop.

Comment: If you have issues after that consider paging your table in some way. How many results do you post to the page?

Comment: I display around 100 to 200 results in table based on date. But when i load page, i am selecting all records which is around 2000 records.

Comment: 100 results is not so bad but 200 is pushing it. This also depends on how may columns you have and if the have large text blocks or blob items.

Answer (score -1):

in dreamweaver I like to do it like this so that is doesn't throw a wobbly...

```
 </tr>
 <%dim bgcolor, counter
 bgcolor = "#E6E8FF"
 counter = 1 %>
 <% 
 While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rsSearch.EOF)) 
 %>
 <% if counter mod 10 = 0 then
       Response.Flush
      End If %>
      <tr bgcolor="<%=bgcolor%>" onMouseOver="changeto(event, '#ECE9D8')" onMouseOut="changeback(event, '<%=bgcolor%>')">
     <td align="left" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsSearch.Fields.Item("NAME").Value)%></td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsSearch.Fields.Item("ID").Value)%></td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsSearch.Fields.Item("WORK_AREA").Value)%></td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsSearch.Fields.Item("VIP_LOGIN").Value)%></td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsSearch.Fields.Item("ACTIVE").Value)%></td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><%= DoDateTime((rsSearch.Fields.Item("LAST_LOGIN_DATE").Value), 1, 1033) %></td>
     <td align="center" valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap"><%=(rsSearch.Fields.Item("EMAIL_ADDRESS").Value)%></td>
   </tr>
   <%counter = counter + 1%>
   <% 
   Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
   Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
   rsSearch.MoveNext()
 Wend
 %>
 </table>
 <br />
```